# How to reshape the input for CNN model in Tensorflow ?

Tags: python, tensorflow, convolution

I am working on a dataset which is a 2-Dimensional. The data looks like below.

```
 pro  packets  bytes  svc_port  durat  U  N  A  C  E  EC  F  PA  R  S
0    1        1     32         0    0.0  0  0  0  0  0   0  0   0  0  0
1    6        1     48        80    0.0  0  0  1  0  0   0  0   0  0  1
2    6        1   1440        22    0.0  0  0  1  0  0   0  0   0  0  0
3    6        1     52        80    0.0  0  0  1  0  0   0  0   0  0  0
4    6        1     52        80    0.0  0  0  1  0  0   0  0   0  0  0
```

I am trying to train a CNN model on this data. The shape of this dataset is (35666, 15)  and the filter is (5,5,1,8).

When I run the model, I got this error.

```
InvalidArgumentError: Shape must be rank 4 but is rank 2 for 'ConvNet_1_1/Conv2D' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,15], [5,5,1,8].
```

I am pretty sure that I need to reshape my input. I don't have height or width since I am not using images here. how can I make the input to 4D ?

Comment: By just looking at your data, it totally doesn't make sense to use CNN. Is there are reason you want to use it? I personally would recommend more traditional machine learning algorithm for this type of data (SVM, random forest, xgboost, etc.)

Comment: Found one research paper implementing CNN model on this data. So trying to imitate. more of a research oriented work. they have mentioned anything about the input reshaping

Comment: In order to make your Conv2D work, you need to shape your 2D array of 15 variables to shape of [5,5,1,8], which is impossible. Moreover, the usage of CNN is built on the assumption that there are local connectivity between adjacent variable values. However, in your tabular data, the variables are not spacial related...

Comment: Can you,  if possible,  provide the research paper you are referring to.  I agree with Zhang that this data doesn't seem fit for CNN. Also,  if at all we wish to continue with CNN, I would recommend 1D CNN. I may be wrong,  but it seems your filter is for a 3D CNN.

Comment: the paper seemed to have used 1D convnet. I am working on it now.

Comment: @rkmalaiya Post it as answer. I ll accept it.